# Save results in a SET and show at the end of the day

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that gets a set and from one hour, shows the number of objects that exist within the set. What I want is for this set to save all occurrences of the day and at 11:59 pm write to a file and at 12:00 pm clean the set and do the same again the next day. Currently what my set is doing is At 11:59 pm it will check how many objects there are and it shows its quantity however it does not match those that occurred for example in the morning.

```
def delayedCounter(delayedSet):
   now = datetime.now()
   date = now.strftime('%Y-%m-d')
   hour = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')
   with open('delayedData.csv', 'a+') as file:
      if hour == '23:59':
         file.write(len(delayedSet)
      elif hour == '00:00':
         delayedSet.clear()
```

i am using apscheduler to do a job to do the main function from time to time as it shows.

```
def trains():
    try:
        data = list(getRequest())
        trainList = getTrain(data)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)



scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(func=trains, trigger='interval', seconds=10 ,max_instances=100, misfire_grace_time=None)
scheduler.start()
```

the function that writes in sets its called getDelayedCSV

```
def getDelayedCSV(trainList):
    delayedSet = set()
    word = 'Atrasado'
    for train in trainList:
        if word in train['status']:
            delayedSet.update([train['id']])
```

The main goal is to store in SET objects that are validated on condition and then at the end of the day, all objects are written to the delayedData.csv file.

Comment: Please show how the objects are being stored and some examples of ones that are missing. Sets contain unique values.

Comment: i updated the code so you can see how i am storing the objects. the only problem i am facing is that if i let the program running alot of hours it should show at least 20 when i print the len(delayedSet) but the only thing that shows up is the current objects from that minute, not the entire day

Comment: Are all your values getting to `getDelayedCSV()` in `trainList` and is `train['id']` unique?

Comment: yes they are all on trainList, then i made the **if** condition to see if they are "delayed" if that condition is **True** then it should write in set ignoring duplicates

Comment: You're creating the `delayedSet` each time `getDelayedCSV` is called. Did you want to initialize it on program startup instead?

Comment: hmmm good point @MatsLindh ... maybe thats the problem but i thought if i would initialize outside of the **for loop** it would work.
so i should initialize as a global variable?

Comment: If you only want it to be unique within the loop, sure - but if you want to keep updating it across scheduled runs, it'll have to be initialized outside of the loop. I would also recommend clearing the set _after_ writing it, and not relying on timestamps to invoke the correct handling.

Comment: its intialized outside of the loop as you can see... and i want to update from time to time. i only want to clear the set at 12pm so i can start again the next day.
the problem is that its not storing all objects that show up during the day